# Check state in Virtual TreeView seems not virtual

Tags: delphi, checkbox, virtualtreeview

I am using Virtual TreeView. In my understanding, since the whole treeview is virtual, the node properties(including the check state) are set on request(such as on a OnData event handler) instead of storing together with the node, since the node is total virtual. However, it seems that Virtual TreeView will store the check state of the node together with the node, instead of obtain from external data source and set on request.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnBeforeGetCheckState` event to handle this in a more virtual manner. The `OnChecking` and `OnChecked` event might also be helpful.